# Webpage won't resize properly

Tags: html, css, position, overlapping

I am attempting to create a business webpage with a two column design. I am trying to have an about us section on one side with some bullets underneath of it. It looks good in the browser in full window view, but when I resize the browser window, my text gets all jumbled and stacked over itself. I am using divs and a container, along with % to place things, but nothing I have tried is working. Any ideas?

Here is the html:

```
<div class = "aboutuscontainer"> 
    <div class = "abouthead"><h2>About us:</h2></div>
    <div class = "aboutinfo"><p>Codes' Decoding is an independant web design company with the consumer's best interests in mind. Created in 2015, we strive to provide only the best in customer satisfaction and web reliability. Since our company is independant, we have the ability to interact directly with the client to offer them the most enjoyable experience possible.</p></div>
    <div class = "qualityhead"><h4>Quality:</h4></div> 
    <div class = "qualityinfo"><p>Here at Codes' Decoding we offer only the highest quality in website design. If you aren't happy, you don't pay. We guarantee you'll love your new site, or your money back!</p></div>
    <br> 
    <div class = "valuehead"><h4>Value:</h4></div> 
    <div class = "valueinfo"><p>When you work with Codes' Decoding you can be assured that you are receiving the best value on the market. Staying independant keeps us in control of our rates and allows us to keep them low for our valued customers.</p></div>  
    <br>  
    <div class = "servicehead"><h4>Service:</h4></div> 
    <div class = "serviceinfo"><p>Our team at Codes' Decoding is 100% dedicated to making sure your experience is perfect. We are there to answer any questions that you may have and our knowledgable team will ensure you have a smooth experience.</p></div>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
            .aboutuscontainer {
            position: relative;
            top: 55px;
            left: 0%;
            border-right: dotted yellow 1px;
            max-width: 51.5%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .abouthead {
            position: absolute;
            color: yellow;
        }

        .aboutinfo {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            top: 90%;
            left: 0px;
            line-height: 1.5em;
        }

        .qualityhead {
            position: absolute;
            color: yellow;
            top: 370%;
            left: 2%;
        }

        .qualityinfo {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            top: 370%;
            left: 13%;
            line-height: 1.5em;  
        }

        .valuehead {
            position: absolute;
            color: yellow;
            top: 570%;
            left: 2%;
        }

        .valueinfo {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            top: 570%;
            left: 13%;
            line-height: 1.5em;  
        }

        .servicehead {
            position: absolute;
            color: yellow;
            top: 790%;
            left: 2%;
        }

        .serviceinfo {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            top: 790%;
            left: 13%;
            line-height: 1.5em;  
        }
```

Comment: Stop using position: absolute.  That will solve a large amount of your problems.  Learn how to get things to position using position relative.

Comment: So I should use position: relative across the entire webpage, or should it be paired with another type?

Comment: Just to follow up for you - position: absolute should be used very sparingly.  Most layouts can be achieved without it.  There are some cases where it makes sense, but it is the exception.

Comment: Okay that makes sense! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was enough changes / suggestions that I thought it was worthwhile to create a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/aaenyenq/

Please note the major revisions to the code:

1. Rather than absolute, use relative positioning.
2. Rather than left / top, allow things to flow, and use some widths.
3. Get the desired left / right arrangement with a method such as display: inline-block or float: left (I tend to prefer display: inline-block).
4. Simplify the code.  Eliminate unnecessary divs (such as around the `h2` and `h4` elements), and use container classes and more generic markup.
5. Removed `<br>` tags.  You should never use them for spacing.  Use margins / padding instead.

Simplified / revised HTML:

```
<div class = "aboutuscontainer"> 
    <h2>About us:</h2>
    <div class="aboutinfo"><p>Codes' Decoding is an independant web design company with the consumer's best interests in mind. Created in 2015, we strive to provide only the best in customer satisfaction and web reliability. Since our company is independant, we have the ability to interact directly with the client to offer them the most enjoyable experience possible.</p></div>
    <div class="listitem">
        <h4>Quality:</h4>
        <div><p>Here at Codes' Decoding we offer only the highest quality in website design. If you aren't happy, you don't pay. We guarantee you'll love your new site, or your money back!</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="listitem">
        <h4>Value:</h4>
        <div><p>When you work with Codes' Decoding you can be assured that you are receiving the best value on the market. Staying independant keeps us in control of our rates and allows us to keep them low for our valued customers.</p></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="listitem">
        <h4>Service:</h4>
        <div><p>Our team at Codes' Decoding is 100% dedicated to making sure your experience is perfect. We are there to answer any questions that you may have and our knowledgable team will ensure you have a smooth experience.</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simplified CSS:

```
   .aboutuscontainer {
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 55px;
        left: 0%;
        border-right: dotted yellow 1px;
        max-width: 51.5%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .aboutuscontainer h2 {
        color: yellow;
    }

    .aboutinfo {
        color: white;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    .listitem h4 {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 20%;
      color: yellow;
    }

    .listitem div {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 78%;
      color: white;
    }
```

NOTE: IF you want different spacing for different sections, you can easily just add a class to the `listitem` div element, then address the different spacing like so:

(Assuming you added a class "service" - `<div class="listitem service">`):

```
    .listitem.service h4 {
         width: 25%;
    }

    .listitem.service div {
         width: 73%;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOO much!! I have been trying to fix that for hours. You have no idea how much that helped. You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use position absolute. I fixed some css for you here. I used float left, and % on the width.

https://jsfiddle.net/gefp9bnd/

```
.qualityhead {
   color: yellow;
   width: 30%;
   float:left;
}
```

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Results in wrapping around the "Quality" line, don't think that is what the OP is after....

Comment: OP can do some adjustment to suit his or her need. :-)